# Best procedure to generate a 5*7 bitmap font

Tags: fonts, lcd, bitmap-fonts

Appart from manual entry,
is there a more efficient method to create C-source code
for a cyrillic 5*7 font suitable for a graphic LCD display?

Comment: The [help/on-topic] pretty clearly says *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Rephrased question to not break forum rules

Answer (score 0):

You could simply take any text/graphics program/library of your choice and a monospace font, generate an image of the glyphs you need, and use that to generate the bitmaps in a shape you want; in your case, probably arrays of 5 `uint8_t`.

That'd be pretty simply to do for example with python and pycairo: just build a for loop over every character you want, draw it into a 5x7 viewport, get the resulting raster image, do whatever you need to do to make it embeddable in your LCD firmware.